# .NET to Docker Hub built success but publish failed

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to publish my .NET Core project to Docker Hub with Visual Studio 2017.

[image: Right click for Publish]

Next, I select Docker Hub & type my credential on the next step.

[image]

This project has been built successfully but failed to publish.
Here is my output.

```
docker build -t "netcore" -f "Dockerfile" --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio" ".."
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.936MB

Step 1/19 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1803 AS base
2.2-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1803: Pulling from microsoft/dotnet
e46172273a4e: Pulling fs layer
68aae72b77f3: Pulling fs layer
61f30f9e4e83: Pulling fs layer
e15c123b212e: Pulling fs layer
021eb2251d67: Pulling fs layer
dc7ca004e96c: Pulling fs layer
ecedf99e17d3: Pulling fs layer
e15c123b212e: Waiting
021eb2251d67: Waiting
dc7ca004e96c: Waiting
ecedf99e17d3: Waiting
image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform
C:\Users\kelvin\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.0.2105168\build\Container.targets(159,5): 
Error MSB3073: The command "docker build -t "netcore" -f "Dockerfile" --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio" ".."" exited with code 1.
2>Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Does anyone has solution for this please?

Comment: "image operating system windows cannot be used on this platform": is your docker installation set to run windows container ? the default is linux containers i remember correctly

Comment: @D.J. I think yes, as this is only my first time to work with Docker. Can you please tell me more detail about your answer?

Comment: you have to explicitely set your docker to run windows. look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-windows-10 for instructions on how to check and set this setting

Comment: OK. Checking on it and will back to here later

Comment: @D.J. Do you have any idea about Docker Toolbox? I am using this instead of Docker for Windows, is installing Docker for WIndows is a must?

Comment: i haven't used "docker toolbox" yet because i didn't need to. maybe you can get along with toolbox instead, i'd say installing docker should be preferred if applicable

Comment: @D.J. I found myself has selected the wrong OS when creating VSProject. Thank a lot for your information to remind my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using Docker Toolbox, 'Linux' must be selected when creating VSProject.
[image]